# Transform regular expression without using pipe

Tags: regex, regex-group

What I'm trying to achieve is a regex expression that can find both `""` and a string starting with `abc_`.
However I cannot use `|` or `^` due to code restrictions.

Do you think there is any chance to transform this regex, by removing the pipe `""|abc_.*` and getting the same result?

https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/2

Comment: `(abc_.*)?("")?` - May be this ? https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/3

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you @rootkonda!

Comment: You are welcome. Posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(abc_.*)?("")?
```

Remember that we are using optional regex character(?). Depending on the input type it may also match a string which contains "". As I understand based on your examples, a given string will contain either "" or abc_.* or some other strings.Hence this is fine.

Demo and explanation:

https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/3